# Ruby - referencing another class inside a self.method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've 2 classes, Person and Membership. Membership has a method called individual_ids which returns an array of ID's, and I'd like to retrieve people with an ID in that array:

```
class Membership

  def self.individuals
    where(membershipable_type: 'individual')
  end

  def self.individuals_ids
    individuals.pluck(:membershipable_id)
  end
end


class Person

  def self.individuals
    Person.where(id: Membership.individuals_ids)
  end

end
```

When I attempt to run Person.individuals, I'm told:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Person::Membership
```

How do I reference the Membership class from inside a self method call as above, rather than it thinking I mean Person.Membership?

Thanks!

Comment: You reference it correctly, the actual question is why it's not loaded. What is the name of the file containing the `Membership` class and where is it located? If you fire the console and type `Membership` do you get *uninitialized constant* error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine when both classes are in the same file. `Membership` class is found by `Person` class :

```
class Membership
  def self.individuals
    puts "Membership.individuals"
  end

  def self.individuals_ids
    puts "Membership.individuals_ids"
  end
end

class Person
  def self.individuals
    puts "Person.individuals"
    Membership.individuals_ids
  end
end

Person.individuals

#=> Person.individuals
#=> Membership.individuals_ids
```

It means your `Membership` class isn't [autoloaded](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) by Rails. You can make sure that `Membership` is defined in `membership.rb` and either :

- move `membership.rb` to `app` folder
- add the required path to [`config.autoload_paths`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths)

Comment: Apologies for wasting your time - was a typo on my part - as you say the code above works fine.

Comment: No problem. Been there, done that. Rails magic can make it hard to debug sometimes.